# Trying to play a song through pygame but get a libmpg123-0.dll error

Tags: python, pygame

Going to keep this short and sweet. I am trying to play a song using pygame's mixer. I have the song titles in a dictionary and are accessing the name of the stored file using this. When I choose the song to play I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\me\Documents\Bella\Music.py", line 50, in <module>
    song_look_up_by_artist("artist1", thisdict)
File "c:\Users\me\Documents\Bella\Music.py",line 37, in song_look_up_by_artist
    mixer.music.load(toplay)
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have found a couple of posts that addressed the issue. They all said close your IDE and restart your computer. I have tried this and nothing. I also found the file that supposedly cannot be found but libmpg123-0.dll is in the pygame's folder. The python file and the .mp3 file are both inside the same folder. I have also put libmpg123-0.dll there as well. I am also using python 3.8.6, windows 10, VScode as my IDE. I don't know what is the real problem. Here is my code if that helps as well.

I found the libmpg123-0.dll file in :\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages

```
from pygame import mixer
import pygame


thisdict = {
        ("artist1", "song1"): 'KDA.mp3',
        ("artist3", "song1"): 'Nanners.mp3',
        ("artist1", "song2"): 'ATL.mp3', 
    }


mixer.init()
#mixer.music.load("C:\Users\Connor Ferwerda\Downloads\\")
#mixer.music.play()


def song_look_up_by_artist(artist, thisdict):
    
    #get list of songs that match artist
    mixer.init()
    song_list = []
    for x in thisdict:
        if x[0] == artist:
            song_list.append(x[1])
    
    #lets user pick if they wanna play a song
    answer = input("Would you like to play a song by " + artist + "? " )
    print("\n")

    if answer == "quit":
        print("ok")
    elif answer == "yes":
        print("Here is there list of songs: ")
        print(song_list)

        #they pick which song
        answer = input("Which song? ")
        for song in song_list: 
            if answer == song:
                toplay = thisdict[(artist, answer)]
                mixer.music.load(toplay)
                mixer.music.play()
                while mixer.music.get_busy():
                    print("playing...")
                    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
            elif song == song_list[-1]:
                print("that doensn't match")
                break

song_look_up_by_artist("artist1", thisdict)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling `pygame`:

```
pip uninstall pygame
```

and then reinstalling the latest version of it:

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: I have just uninstall and re installed pygame and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The path file of the interpreter was wrong. Fixed it with that.